# Exclude category from get_the_category

Tags: loop, exclude, categories

I want to exclude a specific category from the loop, here's what I tried:

Original code:

```
    // auto posts by cat
    if( $bawmrp_options['auto_posts'] == 'cat' || $bawmrp_options['auto_posts'] == 'both' ):
        $cat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        $cat_ids = wp_list_pluck( $cat, 'term_id' );
        $args['category'] = implode( ',', $cat_ids );
    endif;
```

My try:

```
    // auto posts by cat
    if( $bawmrp_options['auto_posts'] == 'cat' || $bawmrp_options['auto_posts'] == 'both' ):
        $cat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        if ($cat->cat_ID != '68') :
            $cat_ids = wp_list_pluck( $cat, 'term_id' );
        endif;
        $args['category'] = implode( ',', $cat_ids );
    endif;
```

In my code I tried to exclude the category 68, but actually the best thing would be if the category has children, then it don't enter in the loop, only it's children

Comment: In your try `$cat` is an array so `$cat->cat_ID` will not work. Was there no error encountered in the above code>

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat_ids = wp_list_pluck( $cat, 'term_id' );
```

Once you get the category ids as you have mentioned above, you can search for the key having the category id `68` as

```
$key = array_search('68', $cat_ids);
```

Once you get the key, you can unset/remove that from the array as

```
unset($cat_ids[$key]);
```

Once that is removed, you can use the implode function the way you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong, but it's still not working, please take a look: http://pastebin.com/gwpydNx1